# What's the correct syntax for OData v4 duration in URI?

Tags: web, syntax, odata, uri, duration

I'm trying to get new products in last day. Having this URI query:

```
example.com/v4/Products?$select=Id,Name,CreatedOnUtc&$filter=CreatedOnUtc ge (now() sub P1D0H0M0.0S)
```

But it returns the message:

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Syntax error at position 37 in 'CreatedOnUtc ge (now() sub P1D0H0M0.0S)'.

What am I having wrong here?

Comment: What did you use to build the OData service?

Comment: @SamXu, It's not my project, so i don't have access to back end. But response header have clues to answer your question:  
**OData-Version**: 4.0  
**Server**: Microsoft-IIS/7.5  
**X-AspNet-Version**: 4.0.30319   
**X-Powered-By**: ASP.NET

Comment: Do you know how to build the backend? Web API OData? Or WCFDS? Or any other? For Web API OData, it doesn't support now().

Comment: @SamXu, turns out it doesn't support `now()` function. I guess I should provide actual [link](http://poodapi.aripaev.ee/v4/Products?$select=Id,Name,ShortDescription,FullDescription,CreatedOnUtc&$filter=CreatedOnUtc%20ge%20(now()%20sub%20P1D0H0M0.0S)). So, how do I get last day products then?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the duration with duration'PT1D0H0M0.0S' (of course, you should replace the quote with %27). Note the PT prefix, not just P.

Please note that OData from MS does not support the function now().

Comment: That duration is wrong. It should be P1DT0H0M0.0S, and can be reduced to P1D. The 'T' in the duration separates the day part (year, month, day, week, whatever) from the time part (hour, minute, second), and all 0-values may be omitted as that is the default.